# Easiest way to convert a Blob into a byte array

Tags: java, mysql, arrays, blob

what is the easiest way to convert a Blob into a byte array?I am using MYSQL and i want to convert a Blob datatype into a byte array.

Iam using java programming language:)

Answer (score 90, accepted):

the mySql blob class has the following function :

> blob.getBytes

use it like this:

```
//(assuming you have a ResultSet named RS)
Blob blob = rs.getBlob("SomeDatabaseField");

int blobLength = (int) blob.length();  
byte[] blobAsBytes = blob.getBytes(1, blobLength);

//release the blob and free up memory. (since JDBC 4.0)
blob.free();
```

Comment: Thanks,actually blob is not having getbytes() method,only serialblob is having getbytes() method.How to do it for blob.

Comment: are you using `java.sql.Blob`?

Comment: this method gives a Lob is closed exception... what do I do ?

Comment: @AnuShibinJosephRaj i think you should post a full question on SO with an example of your code attached.

Comment: is it a good way to just convert a blob in binary and send via httpclient post request?

Comment: @Khan that depends entirely on your situation. what i *can* tell you in advance is that it won't be very fast..

Answer (score 60):

The **easiest** way is this.

```
byte[] bytes = resultSet.getBytes("my_field");
```

Comment: Excuse me, but I really I have not understood what `rs` is.

Comment: @MarcoSulla: A JDBC `ResultSet`

Comment: I believe this answer is valid only when the field is less than 1048576 bytes.

Comment: @AJ.P: This depends on the SQL dialect. In many dialects, there is no such restriction.

Answer (score 0):

You can also get bytes array from Blob instance by this way:

```
Blob myBlob = null;
byte[] bytes = myBlob.getBinaryStream().readAllBytes();
```