# image display using play framework and scala

Tags: scala, view, playframework

Is there any way to the path of image in the database and display it on view page and how to display image in view page using playframework2.0

Answer (score 3):

html:

```
@(name:String)
    <img class="myClass" alt="myAlt" src="@routes.Application.image(name)">
```

Controller:

```
object Application extends Controller {

         def image(name:String) = Action {

                val MimeType = "image/png"
                try {
                       val imageData: Array[Byte] = fetchImageFromDatabase(name)
                       Ok(imageData).as(MimeType)
                }
                catch {
                   case e: IllegalArgumentException =>
                    BadRequest("Couldn’t generate image. Error: " + e.getMessage)
                }
        }

        def fetchImageFromDatabase(name: String): Array[Byte] = {
         //import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream
         //import java.awt.image.BufferedImage
          ......
        }
    }
```

routes:

```
GET /images/:name controllers.Application.image(name: String)
```

Comment: ...thnx!...  the fetchImageFromDatabase function for what use and please be expand that method

Comment: You mention about database - so you have to read it from database and convert to byte array

Comment: my database table name :post and the fields are id,name and image

Comment: See [Easiest way to convert a Blob into a byte array](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6662933/651140)