# how to convert BLOB type to MultipartFile?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, blob, multipartfile

in my project i stored an attachment to mysql db as BLOB, but i need to retrieve it as a multipartfile.
here is my code samples and i need to complete this

```
try {
    Connection conn = this.getConnection();
    try(PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        stmt.setInt(1,mail_id);
        try(ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
            while (rs.next()){

                mailModel.setEmailId(rs.getInt("email_id"));
                mailModel.setEmailAddress(rs.getString("email_address"));
                mailModel.setMsgTemplate(rs.getString("msg_template"));
                mailModel.setPriority(rs.getInt("priority"));
                String jsonData = rs.getString("parameters");
                List<MailModel.Parameter> parameters = parseJsonParameters(jsonData);
                mailModel.setParameters(parameters);

                Blob blob = rs.getBlob("attachment");
                
            }
            return mailModel;
        }
    }
}
```

i need to complete that smtp

Comment: What method do you call that requires a `MultipartFile` type?

Comment: Please share a [mcve]

Comment: Just think of the blob as a file - in the end both are just byte arrays. The difference is how you address those byte arrays. So if you look for how to attach a file to an email you'll probably come across the use of a byte array or byte stream. Instead of getting this from a file just get it from your blob.

Comment: this is the model
 private int emailId;
    private String emailAddress;
    private String msgTemplate;
    private int priority;
    private List<Parameter> parameters;
    private MultipartFile attachment;

Comment: Convert BLOB to byte[] https://stackoverflow.com/a/6662559/7218656 + Convert byte[] to Multipart https://stackoverflow.com/a/18383557/7218656

Comment: now i coverted blob to byte[] but i need to convert that to multipartfile :)

Comment: @ChandraMayou I've shared two links in my previous comment, please read it completely